# Why my .NET error log file is showing lots of NUL characters in it

Tags: c#

I am using c#, and I have got Logging in my project.

When I see my log file, it is showing lots of **'NUL'** characters, just to correct you **it is not 'NULL'**.

Please suggest what could be the reason of showing 'NUL' characters.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of logging are you using? And is it possible your logging is outputting a Unicode file and you're reading it with a tool that doesn't understand Unicode?

Comment: Just a simple, I have got my class and methods, In which we are just passing the values whenever logs are required, and we are not using any tool for logging.

Comment: can you show us some code? You are not giving any useful information here.

Comment: A string in C# is UCS-16.  If you save a C# string as a "binary" then each character will have 16 bits.  Most editor assume UTF-8 (8 bits per character).  Hence, you will see a NUL after every correct "character".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUL is the abbreviation of the null character (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

Some text editors will represent this as shown in [this image](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/24/nulnotepad.jpg) which is what I think you're seeing.

As for why you're seeing it, I'm guessing (and you haven't offered much to go on, what text editor are you using?) you have an option set in the text editor to view control characters.